# Vim color problem

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I've a strange problem with vim editor:
if i write a simple text, all is normal, white text

[image]

If i add shebang, save and exit...reopen and ..color change after first line!

[image]

:(( Can you help me?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `:echo b:current_syntax`? (From inside vim of course)

Comment: E121: Undefined variable: b:current_syntax

Comment: I think this is a recent bug in Vim: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11977, but the fix hasn't been packaged yet, perhaps.

Comment: What is the Vim version and what patches are included in the release (this info is had from `vim --version`, at the top)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as said by @muru ...problem solved upgrading vim! thanks to all

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please add a full answer.